# Excel: Split a delimited string and retrieve a numerical value of each element in the string

Tags: string, vba, excel

I have the following situation: 
In a sheet (Dropdown) I have 2 columns containing product names and their respective IDs. In a different sheet (SelectProduct) I have a dropdown list of the product names for which I wrote some VBA code to allow multiple selection.

What way is there to perform something like a split on the string of products and retrieve EACH product's ID, then put each ID in a different cell as a string?

eg. initial string in Cell A2 is Product1;Product2;Product3, I want to end up with ID1;ID2;ID3 in another cell.

EDIT: Above was just an example to get an idea of what I need.
My column has 606 products, with IDs ranging from 1 to 606

another example: string in cell- Tire;Bumper;Helmet

the outcome of IDs of those specific products- 156;35;310

the IDs won't be in order, as it depends on the order the products were selected.

Comment: maybe not the **best** solution, but perhaps a UDF that loads cell A2 into an array using the `Split` method, than you can look up each id and write it back to the cell?

Comment: where are the ID values?  One way would be to read the string in as a variable, split the variable in to an array using the ";" as the delimiter, loop through the array looking up each ID value for the items in the array, joining the resulting matches up in to a string and spit that string out to a sheet.

Comment: If it's always going to say 'Product', then why not just replace 'Product' with 'ID'? MsgBox Replace(Application.Range("A2"), "Product", "ID")

Comment: @sous2817 The ID values are in the sheet Dropdown, along with the names of the producuts.

Comment: @PractLogical they aren't "ProductX", it was just an example for a quicker explanation.

Comment: not sure what you are getting at. A cell has multiple alphanumeric codes separated by a ;. and you want to get just the numerical values separated by ;????

Comment: @user3005775 each alphanumeric code is the name of a product, and each product has a certain ID. I need the IDs of each product into a string separated by ; as well, to send it to a Stored Procedure and retrieve information about those products from a SQL table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the lookup table in **C3:D10** and data in **A1**, this little *UDF()*:

```
Public Function GetIds(r1 As Range, r2 As Range) As String
   Dim t As String
   ary = Split(r1.Text, ";")
   For Each a In ary
      For i = 1 To r2.Rows.Count
         If a = r2(i, 1).Value Then
            GetIds = GetIds & ";" & r2(i, 2)
         End If
      Next i
   Next a
   GetIds = Mid(GetIds, 2)
End Function
```

will produce:

[image]

The IDs can be either numerical or non-numerical

Comment: exactly what I was thinking / suggesting :)

Comment: as I was looking into Scott's suggestion, you posted this. it looks wonders and in theory should work, however it gives me the #NAME? error. My IDs are in a different sheet. I am calling the function as =GetIds(A2, Dropdown!B1:C606). what am I missing?

Comment: I tried putting the list of products in the same sheet where I call the function. still get #NAME?

Comment: @Hidoshi The error message means Excel can't "find" the *UDF()*....... **make sure the UDF() is located in a Standard Module.**

Comment: @Gary'sStudent It's working perfectly, thank you very much for the help.
And thank you Scott for suggesting the same idea.

Answer (score 0):

As quick approach I would do this:

First, I would split by the separator (which I understood being a semi-column):

```
a = "Product1;Product2;Product3"
b = Split(a, ";")
```

In that case, `b` will be an array of elements. Hence, I would parse starting from right until I don't find any number any longer:

```
Set c = New Collection
For j = 0 To UBound(b)
    cnt1 = ""
    cnt2 = 1
    Do While IsNumeric(Left(Right(b(j), cnt2), 1))
        cnt1 = Left(Right(b(j), cnt2), 1) & cnt1
        cnt2 = cnt2 + 1
    Loop
    c.Add "ID" & cnt1
Next j
```

Please note your "ID + number" will be in the collection `c`.
Which means you can build them up by just looping once through it:

```
newString = ""
For Each element In c
    newString = element & ";"
Next element
```

P.s. I believe though studying a solution using RegEx (Regular Expressions) would be more efficient, the pattern is not too complex.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, to get ID#s, would be to loop through each character and strip out any non alpha numberic.

```
str2 = ""
str1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value
For i = 1 To Len(str1)
c = Mid(str1, i, 1)
If IsNumeric(c) Or c = ";" Then
str2 = str2 & c
End If
Next i
```

just set A1 to whatever range your cell is in,

the str2 will bee all numbers with ; separater